# Background Image is not responsive and stretched in reactjs and tailwindcss

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have created this one of the challenges from frontend-mentor that is of a farm-fruits, i did everything correct except for the home page background image. The code for Home.js is following:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import headimgd from '../assets/images/desktop/image-header.jpg'
import headimgm from '../assets/images/mobile/image-header.jpg'
import hamburger from '../assets/images/icon-hamburger.svg'
import arrow from '../assets/images/icon-arrow-down.svg'

const Navbar = () => {
    
      
    const [navBarOpen, setNavBarOpen] = useState(false)

    const handleOpen = () => {
        setNavBarOpen(!navBarOpen)
    }


  return (
      <div>
          <div className='flex justify-between py-7 items-center'>
              <h1 className='font-barlow font-bold text-white tracking-wide text-xl px-5 '>sunnyside</h1>
              
              <button onClick={handleOpen} className="relative">
                  {navBarOpen ? <ul className='absolute top-0 right-10 bg-white py-4 mt-8 px-20 w-80'>
                      <li className=" px-4 mx-4  py-2 text-grayBlue font-bold tracking-wide font-barlow text-sm">About</li>
                      <li className=" px-4 mx-4  py-2 text-grayBlue font-bold tracking-wide font-barlow text-sm">Services</li>
                      <li className=" px-4 mx-4  py-2 text-grayBlue font-bold tracking-wide font-barlow text-sm">Projects</li>
                      <li className=" px-4 mx-4 mt-2 font-fraunces bg-softYellow px-4 py-3 rounded-full font-bold uppercase text-xs"> Contact</li> </ul>
                      : <div></div>
                  }
                  <img src={hamburger} alt="menu" className='px-5 lg:hidden' />
                 
              </button>



              <nav className='hidden lg:flex '>
                  <ul className='hidden lg:flex px-5 items-center'>
                       <li className='ml-4 text-white font-barlow text-sm'>About</li> 
                       <li className='ml-4 text-white font-barlow text-sm'>Services</li> 
                       <li className='ml-4 text-white font-barlow text-sm'>Projects</li> 
                       <li className='ml-8 font-fraunces bg-white px-4 py-2 rounded-full uppercase text-xs'>Contact</li>  
                  </ul>
              </nav>
             
         
              


          </div>
          <h1 className='font-fraunces text-white text-[50px] uppercase font-bold text-center tracking-widest'>We are creatives</h1>
          <img src={arrow} alt="arrow" className='mx-auto mt-10 pt-10' />
          <div className='grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2 grid-row-auto'>
            <img src={headimgm} alt="orange" className='absolute top-0  -z-10 md:hidden' />
              <img src={headimgd} alt="orange" className='hidden md:block absolute  top-0 -z-10 col-span-2 h-[821px] w-screen ' />
              
          </div>
          
      </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

The images below this home page are over the homepage bg-image,i lack css tbh, attaching the screenshot of the build:
[image]

the egg and its description are separate section i am not sure where i made the mistake and egg and description need to be in opposite places egg-right descrip-left just like in design but this is my first time working with responsive pages. Attaching the og design
[image]

also if you could help me about css i mean where can i learn it better tried w3schools wasnt effective for me
thanks in advance <3

Comment: Try to use `bg-cover` class in images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake while making it responsive just incase if you are a newbie to working with responsive pages using tailwind css do not mix desktop version images with mobile version images. the little changes are as followed:

```
import React from 'react'
import egg from '../assets/images/mobile/image-transform.jpg'
import eggd from '../assets/images/desktop/image-transform.jpg'
import standm from '../assets/images/mobile/image-stand-out.jpg'
import standd from '../assets/images/desktop/image-stand-out.jpg'
import graphicm from '../assets/images/mobile/image-graphic-design.jpg'
import graphicd from '../assets/images/desktop/image-graphic-design.jpg'
import photographym from '../assets/images/mobile/image-photography.jpg'
import photographyd from '../assets/images/desktop/image-photography.jpg'

const Body = () => {
  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 mt-32 md:grid-cols-2 auto-rows-auto md:mt-8 lg:mt-40 xl:mt-96 pt-10 w-full 2xl:pt-72 2xl:mt-44">
    {/* ---------- TRANSFORM YOUR BRAND ------------ */}
    <img  src={egg} alt='egg' className='md: hidden' />
    <div className="bg-white">
    <div className="pt-10 pb-5 px-6 md:px-10 md:pb-3 md:pt-3 lg:px-20 lg:pt-20 lg:pb-5 xl:pt-44 ">
      <h1 className="font-fraunces font-bold text-center text-4xl tracking-wide lg:text-left lg:w-96 text-desBlue ">
        Transform your brand
      </h1>
      <p className="text-center pt-8 font-barlow px-6 lg:px-0 lg:pr-14 xl:pr-36 text-grayishBlue text-md lg:text-left">
        We are a full-service creative agency specializing in helping brands
        grow fast. Engage your clients through compelling visuals that do
        most of the marketing for you.
      </p>

      <div className="text-center">
        <button className="uppercase font-fraunces pt-8 border-b-8 border-yellow-200 rounded font-bold tracking-wide text-desBlue">
          Learn More
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img
  src={eggd}
  alt="egg"
  className="hidden md:flex w-full"
```

do not forget comments as you would look clearly i was adding mobile image with (m) on desktop version

Answer (score 0):

Hope so this will work for you code

```
<div className="h-64 w-64">
    <img
    className="max-w-full h-auto object-cover object-center"
    src="/images/myImage.jpg"
    alt="My image"
    />
```